How to save a Scoped Variable Between Middleware and Services in .NET Core?
I'm trying to build a hierarchical logging structure in a .NET Core API. My goal is to generate a log ID in a middleware and use it as a parent ID for logs in subsequent API calls. I want each API hit to have a unique log ID, which should be accessible across my services.
Here’s what I’ve done so far:

I created a LoggingMiddleware that generates the log ID.
I store the log ID in a LogIdSaver class registered as a scoped service.
I inject LogIdSaver into my DashboardService to access the log ID.

The issue I'm facing is that the middleware can’t seem to inject the LogIdSaver correctly, leading to errors. My middleware needs to save the log ID generated and make it accessible to my service, but it doesn’t seem to work as expected.
Code:
Startup.cs:
namespace ElasticsearchApi
{
    public class Startup
    {
        public void ConfigureServices(IServiceCollection services)
        {
            services.AddSingleton<Logger>();
            services.AddScoped<LogIdSaver>(); // saving the logId
            services.AddScoped<DashboardService>();
            services.AddControllers();
        }

        public void Configure(IApplicationBuilder app, IWebHostEnvironment env)
        {
            app.UseMiddleware<LoggingMiddleware>();
            app.UseRouting();
            app.UseAuthorization();
            app.UseEndpoints(endpoints => { endpoints.MapControllers(); });
        }
    }
}

LoggingMiddleware.cs:
namespace ElasticsearchApi.ElasticsearchLibrary
{
    public class LoggingMiddleware
    {
        private readonly RequestDelegate _next;
        private readonly Logger _logger;
        private readonly LogIdSaver _logIdSaver;

        public LoggingMiddleware(RequestDelegate next, Logger logger, LogIdSaver logSaver)
        {
            _next = next;
            _logger = logger;
            _logIdSaver = logSaver;
        }

        public async Task InvokeAsync(HttpContext context)
        {
            var parentLogId = context.Request.Headers["LogId"].FirstOrDefault() ?? "";
            if (string.IsNullOrEmpty(parentLogId))
                _logIdSaver.logId = await _logger.LogNew(new Log());
            else
                _logIdSaver.logId = await _logger.LogNew(new Log(), parentLogId);

            context.Response.OnCompleted(async () => { await _logger.LogComplete(_logIdSaver.logId); });

            await _next(context);
        }
    }
}

DashboardService.cs:
namespace ElasticsearchApi.Services
{
    public class DashboardService
    {
        private readonly Logger _logger;
        private readonly LogIdSaver _logIdSaver;

        public DashboardService(Logger logger, LogIdSaver logSaver)
        {
            _logger = logger;
            _logIdSaver = logSaver;
        }

        public async Task<List<Document>> GetAllDocuments()
        {
            Console.WriteLine(_logIdSaver.LogId); // To verify if the log ID from middleware is correctly accessed
            var documents = await CallApi.CallGetAllDocuments(_logIdSaver.LogId);
            return documents;
        }
    }
}

Problem:
The LogIdSaver instance in the middleware doesn’t seem to retain the log ID correctly across the middleware and the services. How can I persist the log ID generated in the middleware so that it can be accessed consistently in my services? Is there a better approach to store this ID per API hit in a thread-safe way?
Any advice or solution would be greatly appreciated. Thanks!

You can stash extra properties in the feature collection of the HttpContext eg https://github.com/dotnet/aspnetcore/blob/main/src/Http/Http.Abstractions/src/Routing/EndpointHttpContextExtensions.cs#L22

@JeremyLakeman Thank you for this solution, it can work for me, but the best way for my case was Karl answer

Middlewares that don't implement IMiddleware are created as singletons so if you take your LogIdSaver it won't be the same instance that is returned when requesting it later in the pipeline (ie in your controller).
So one way to do this is to implement IMiddleware which will use IMiddlewareFactory to create new instances of your middleware for each activation.
You can read more about that here: https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/aspnet/core/fundamentals/middleware/extensibility?view=aspnetcore-8.0#imiddleware
You do however have another solution, and that is to simply move your LogIdSaver to your invocation method.
        public LoggingMiddleware(RequestDelegate next, Logger logger)
        {
            _next = next;
            _logger = logger;
        }

        public async Task InvokeAsync(HttpContext context, LogIdSaver logSaver)
        {
            var parentLogId = context.Request.Headers["LogId"].FirstOrDefault() ?? "";
            if (string.IsNullOrEmpty(parentLogId))
                logSaver.logId = await _logger.LogNew(new Log());
            else
                logSaver.logId = await _logger.LogNew(new Log(), parentLogId);

            context.Response.OnCompleted(async () => { await _logger.LogComplete(logSaver.logId); });

            await _next(context);
        }

I usually prefer the IMiddleware route since it feels cleaner to me but the result should be the same.

Thank you a lot, one of my friends suggested another solution which is using var _logSaver = context.RequestServices.GetRequiredService<LogIdSaver>(); inside the public async Task InvokeAsync(HttpContext context), is that a good approach or should I stick with the IMiddleware approach?

That is basically what happens in the background, but instead of getting it injected you retrieve it yourself. It makes it more complicated to setup a unit test for the middleware though since you would have to mock stuff on the HttpContext so I would still prefer the dependency injection way (ie taking it in the method arguments or the constructor).

Thank you a lot for the explanation, I appreciate that.
